# A CUDA cudaMemcpy issue

Tags: memory, cuda

I have been given an assignment for a simple CUDA program to calculate the histogram of an input of integers with values between 1 to 256. For some reason, when I attempt to copy the results from the device memory to the host memory it fails. It gives me an error 11 ("cudaErrorInvalidValue"). As far as I can see everything in that regards should work. Can someone please take a look and tell me what am I missing?

```
#define NUM_THREADS 256

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int histogram[NUM_THREADS + 1] = { 0 };
    int values[] = { 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    int *dev_histogram = 0;
    int *dev_values = 0;

    memory_setup(dev_histogram, values, dev_values, values[0]);
    gpu_operations(histogram, dev_histogram, dev_values, values[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        printf("%d : %d\n",i, histogram[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int memory_setup(int* dev_histogram, int* values_arr, int* dev_values_arr, int num_values) {

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_histogram, (NUM_THREADS + 1) * sizeof(int));

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {

        printf("ERROR: CUDA memory allocation operation failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_values_arr, num_values * sizeof(int));

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {

        printf("ERROR: CUDA memory allocation operation failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_values_arr, values_arr, num_values * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {

        printf("ERROR: CUDA memory copying operation failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 1;
}

void gpu_operations(int* histogram, int* dev_histogram, int* dev_values_arr, int num_values) {

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    int num_blocks = num_values / NUM_THREADS + num_values % NUM_THREADS != 0;
    
    kernel_histogram <<<num_blocks, NUM_THREADS>>>(dev_histogram, dev_values_arr);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(histogram, dev_histogram, (NUM_THREADS + 1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("ERROR: CUDA memory copying operation failed4, %d \n", cudaStatus);
        return;
    }

    cudaFree(dev_histogram);
    cudaFree(dev_values_arr);
}

__global__ void kernel_histogram(int* dev_histogram, int* dev_values_arr) {

    __shared__ int temp[NUM_THREADS + 1];

    temp[threadIdx.x] = 0;
    __syncthreads();

    int thread_id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int thread_value = dev_values_arr[thread_id];

    atomicAdd(&temp[thread_value], 1);
    __syncthreads();

    atomicAdd(&(dev_histogram[threadIdx.x]), temp[threadIdx.x]);
}
```

Comment: you can't pass pointers the way you are doing to your `memory_setup` routine and allocate those pointers properly for use elsewhere.  After you fix that, you will have other problems in your kernel code to chase.  But the invalid value error is due to the way you are attempting to allocate `dev_histogram` and `dev_values_arr`. I will locate a duplicate question eventually.

Comment: note that you have several other errors in your code.  I'm not suggesting the linked duplicate fixes all the errors.  However for the question you are asking, it is the correct solution.

Comment: You are compiling this code with a C++ compiler, so take a couple of minutes to study house references work in C++. Life will be considerably easier if you do